# Momentum equation in collision of a particle and a droplet

Tags: fluid-dynamics, collision

When a solid particle which moves with a constant velocity has a head-on collision with a water droplet, at the exact moment of collision, a sudden decrease happens in particle velocity, and then particle starts penetrating into droplet.

Since the collision is not fully elastic, I'm wondering how I can write a proper momentum balance for before and after collision.
(whether by defining an empirical coefficient for momentum loss due to impact, or ...)

Answer (score 1):

The momentum will change in accordance with the usual laws of physics:

$$p_t= p_0 +\int F dt$$

(If F is opposite to the momentum it will result in a decrease). Depending on the shape of the particle, the value of $F$ will vary with depth of penetration. It will also depend on the velocity, size, viscosity, ...

Comment: Thanks Floris, I'm looking for an applied momentum equation that I can use it with my experimental results. Therefore, there should be only those parameters in that equation which are measurable for me (mass, velocity, etc). Can I introduce a coefficient of momentum loss $C_l$ for the velocity drop at the collision moment, saying that: $m_p$$v_p$+$m_d$$v_d=(1-$$C_l)(m_p$$v_p$+$m_d$$v_d)$ in which right hand is for before impact, and left hand parameters are for after impact?

Comment: @Nick you are mistaken to think the velocity must change instantaneously at the boundary. As long as the force is finite, it will take a finite time for the velocity to change. That said, there is an interesting theorem about how far a particle will penetrate - basically it will lose most of its speed when the displaced mass is equal to the mass of the particle - so denser materials penetrate deeper, as do longer arrows.

Comment: Thanks Floris. I use a high speed camera to investigate this phenomenon and I've got some interesting results so far. There is a sudden decrease in particle velocity as it hits the droplet and interestingly, the particle velocity again increases as particle penetrates into droplet (due to interfacial forces). I think it'd be very helpful if I can email 2-pages illustrated report that I've written from my data on those experiments. If you agree, please let me have your email address. Mine is: h.banitabaei@gmail.com     Thanks so much